# Style arrow in menu

Tags: html, css

i am using some simple menu CSS, some parts need to be unpuck and to let my website users know this menu have some submenu options i want to put arrow close to it.

It should look like: 
http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_19971213581407508176.jpg

And my code looks like:

**CSS**

```
.filter{
    margin-left:20px;
    position: relative;
}

.filter a{
    color: #888888;
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
}

li:after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url("../images/filter_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 480px;
    top: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="filter">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Progress</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Claimed number</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Make</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Status</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Yea sorry guys i forgot on some CSS i am using above as well in my other code, its:

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

li{
    display: inline;
}
```

Is here anyone who can help me to fix this problem with arrows? Because on my version they are just randomly separate on website at the moment.

Comment: Can you give us all the relevant code you have so far? [This is what your current code gives us](http://jsbin.com/hiqigati/1/edit)

Comment: As a first thought you could try `li a:after {}` instead of `li:after {}` but as @ZachSaucier said, a working jsfiddle or something would help us help you..

Comment: @ZachSaucier Sorry i edit it
and 
EllaRyan Arrow dont need to be a href but thanks anyway, good point

Comment: The problem is you have set the `:after` to be position absolute (which is fine) but you haven't set the `li` to `position:relative` which would be more logical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

this should help you, insert the triangle using

```
<span class=".arrow-down"></span>
```

or ::after.

```
.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, in this situation its helpfull :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use unicode arrow sign :)

▾ `&#9662;`

or

▼ `&#9660;`